# Result of call to 'sorted(by:)' is unused

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I am trying to sorted my array with higher to lower vote, I am able to append value in array, But when I tried to sorted it, It showing warning of `Result of call to 'sorted(by:)' is unused`

**My code is -**

```
struct WallAction {
    var upVote:Int?
    var downVote:Int?
    var noVote:String?
}

var wallActionList = [WallAction]()
var up = 0
var down = 0
var noVote = ""

for (j,wallActn) in wall.1["wallAction"] {
    if wallActn["action"].stringValue == ""{
        self.noVote = "Vote"
    }
    if wallActn["action"].stringValue == "1"{
        self.up += 1
    }
    if wallActn["action"].stringValue == "0"{
        self.down += 1
    }
    
}
let wallAct = WallAction(upVote: self.up, downVote: self.down, noVote: self.noVote)
self.wallActionList.append(wallAct)
self.wallActionList.sorted(by: { $0.upVote! > $1.upVote! }) // Result of call to 'sorted(by:)' is unused
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `sort(by:)` instead? (without `ed`)

Comment: @Sweeper I just want to sort by any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.sorted(by: )
```

returns the sorted array, if you need the sorted array and leave the original array untouched.

```
.sort(by:)
```

it doesn't returns anything, it sorts the original array.
If you don't care about original array being modified, then use `.sort(by:)`